# Get 301 status code when sending GET request with parameter

Tags: http, go, httpserver, gorilla, mux

I have a very simple Go server code setup with `mux` and when I use `curl` with `GET` request params (`localhost:8080/suggestions/?locale=en`), I get 301 status code (Move permanently). But when there's no get parameters, it's working just fine.

```
func main() {
router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
router.HandleFunc("/suggestions", handleSuggestions).Methods("GET")
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8080", router))
}
```

Can somebody shed me a light on this.Thanks

Comment: I did mention that I use curl command line :)

Answer (score 4):

go doc mux.StrictSlash states:

```
func (r *Router) StrictSlash(value bool) *Router
    StrictSlash defines the trailing slash behavior for new routes. The initial
    value is false.

    When true, if the route path is "/path/", accessing "/path" will redirect to
    the former and vice versa. In other words, your application will always see
    the path as specified in the route.

    When false, if the route path is "/path", accessing "/path/" will not match
    this route and vice versa.

    Special case: when a route sets a path prefix using the PathPrefix() method,
    strict slash is ignored for that route because the redirect behavior can't
    be determined from a prefix alone. However, any subrouters created from that
    route inherit the original StrictSlash setting.
```

So to avoid the redirects you can either `mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(false)` which is equivalent to `mux.NewRouter()` or use a URL with a trailing slash i.e. `router.HandleFunc("/suggestions/", handleSuggestions).Methods("GET")`

Answer (score 3):

That's simply because you registered the path `/suggestions` (note: there is no trailing slash), and you call the URL `localhost:8080/suggestions/?locale=en` (there is a trailing slash after `/suggestions`).

You router detects that there's a registered path which would match the requested path without the trailing slash (based on your [`Router.StrictSlash()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.StrictSlash) policy), so it sends a redirect which when followed would lead you to a valid, registered path.

Simply use a URL without trailing slash after `suggestions`:

```
localhost:8080/suggestions?locale=en
```